# Power BI: GroupBy Column in Table Visualization w/o Code

Tags: group-by, datatables, powerbi, data-visualization, dynamics-365

Been a while since I've used Power BI and trying to find a no DAX code solution to group by column in Table visualization for a D365 CRM Online dashboard. I have the following table visualization in Power BI desktop:

[image]

I want to be able to group by Account Name column so that the table visualization looks as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with out having to create another data source table and/or without using DAX.  I feel that this would be a very common task which MS would provide a no code solution for in Power BI. So far I am only finding solution using DAX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

No data changes needed at all!

On the left, we've got your data in a classic table.  We need to change it into a matrix, as shown on the right.  So, click your visual over to matrix and then try out the layout and formatting changes below.

In the Layout section, put both `[Account Name]` and `[Product Group]` as rows.

Go into Format Pane (the paint roller) and tweak these attributes:

- Under the Style card set the style dropdown to None
- Under the Grid card, set the Horizontal and Vertical grids to 'On' (manage color and thickness as it suits you)
- Under Row Headers, set Stepped layout to off.

I think that does what you're after.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The below link has the details you are looking for:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Grouping-table-rows-based-on-values/m-p/365600#M165332

You will have to use a matrix instead of a table.